# in WebView, how to know which button is clicked?

Tags: java, android

Android: guys i want to detect which button is clicked by the user. 
The image below will help me to explain my problem.

I load google inside my WebView.

[image]

I dont have any idea on how to do this.
Please help me, im using java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use WebViewClient for this purpose. below is link for sample URL

http://marakana.com/forums/android/examples/58.html

Comment: but how can i detect which button is click?

Comment: Whenever button is clicked then below callback will be called             @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }                                                              if wanted to do some specific action then you can write inside this call back

Comment: shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) method is not always called when I click a button.